# How to remove validation error from HTML5 input?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

A client has a contact form that is submitted using an AJAX callback. After completing the AJAX request, the form fields are cleared.

This is where the problem manifests: the emptied form fields are instantly marked as errorous by the browser.

Is there a way to remove the validation error using JavaScript?

Comment: You could 'remember' the input from the user, and then replace it afterwards. What kind of button are you using to submit it? Is it inside the `<form>` element?

Comment: Yes, it's a standard submit input that will simply send a POST request with JavaScript off. But with JS on, it has a callback attached that sends an AJAX request instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reset HTML5 invalid input state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608780/reset-html5-invalid-input-state)

Comment: The fields are required="required". When they are emptied, the browser gives a standard error, marking the fields with a red frame.

Comment: The fields in that case, you need to remove the button from the `<form>` element. If you do that, then it will not submit automatically or empty the form fields.

Comment: no, the form fields aren't emptied by the submit input, but rather manually using javascript. This is the whole problem. Kyle's answer solves it though, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't clear individual values, just use the `reset()` function on the form element. This clears the form to its original (empty) state and no errors appear.

Comment: Indeed, that seems to reset the values and validation as well. Cheers!